# XlsxWriter with Pandas Error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas.ExcelWriter to add conditional formatting to a spreadsheet which im creating using df.to_excel.  When I hard code the cell range, as seen below, the code works fine.

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A3:N361386', {'type' : 'no_blanks', 'format' : worksheet_format})
```

But when i parameterize it, like the below, i get an error. Any ideas?

```
Data_Range = "'" + 'A3:' + str(chr(len(THIS_proposals_data.columns)+96)).upper() + str(len(THIS_proposals_data.index)) + "'"

worksheet.conditional_format(str(Data_Range), {'type' : 'no_blanks', 'format' : worksheet_format})
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-25e65d1fb126>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/EHARTMAN/Desktop/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/EHARTMAN/Desktop')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/EHARTMAN/Desktop/untitled1.py", line 64, in <module>
    worksheet.conditional_format(Data_Range, {'type' : 'no_blanks', 'format' : worksheet_format})

  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 85, in cell_wrapper
    row_1, col_1 = xl_cell_to_rowcol(cell_1)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\utility.py", line 108, in xl_cell_to_rowcol
    col_str = match.group(2)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap it in quotes. Replace:

```
Data_Range = "'" + 'A3:' + str(chr(len(THIS_proposals_data.columns)+96)).upper() + str(len(THIS_proposals_data.index)) + "'"
```

with:

```
Data_Range = 'A3:' + str(chr(len(THIS_proposals_data.columns)+96)).upper() + str(len(THIS_proposals_data.index))
```

Comment: Ok, one second i'll test it quick. Thank you.

Comment: How to write 'A:L' to avoid rows numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a string range you can use a row-col range like `(first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col)`, see the [XlsxWriter conditional_format docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-conditional-format).

For example:

```
worksheet.conditional_format(0, 0, 4, 1, {...})  # Same as below.
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:B5',    {...})
```

Note, it is a general rule in XlsxWriter that anywhere you can use an A1 range you can use a Row-Col range which is easier to set up programmatically (see [XlsxWriter: Working with Cell Notation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_cell_notation.html)).

For places where a string range is required, for example in formulas, you can use the [XlsxWriter: Cell Utility Functions](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-utility-functions).